# flutter: Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, widget

in a class, I added a variable of type Widgt and a variable of type String variable but, which I show in another class (stateful widget) that I display on the screen. but when I open the page, there is a red screen with writing: Expected a value of type 'Widget', but got one of type 'Null'. Can you help me please ?here I declare the variable:

````
  String missionNumber = "";
  String missionName = "";
  String description = "";
  String secondDescription = "";
  List<int> points = [];
  int userPoints = 0;
  Widget widget = Text("REPLACE THIS TEXT BY YOUR WIDGET");
  Widget secondWidget = Text("REPLACE THIS TEXT BY YOUR  Second WIDGET");



  Mission(missionNumber, missionName, description, points, widget,{userPoints,secondWidget,secondDescription}){
    this.missionNumber = missionNumber;
    this.missionName = missionName;
    this.description = description;
    this.points = points;
    this.widget = widget;
    this.secondWidget = secondWidget;
    this.secondDescription = secondDescription;

  }

}```
here I use it in a class:
class MultipleTextMissionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const MultipleTextMissionCard({Key? key,
    @required this.missionNumber,
    @required this.missionName,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.points,
    required this.widget,
    this.secondDescription,
    this.secondWidget
  }) : super(key: key)
  ;
  final missionNumber;
  final missionName;
  final description;
  final points;
  final Widget widget;
  final secondDescription;
  final secondWidget;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 10,
      child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text(missionNumber),
                Text(missionName,style:
                TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20
                )
                ),
                Text("0/${points.last}"),

              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 5,),
            Text(description),
            widget,
            Text(secondDescription),
            secondWidget
          ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
here, I declare the variable:
```Mission mission3 = Mission(
      "M03",
      "Unload Cargo Plane",
      "does the cargo door stay completely down \n     and touch the black frame?",
      [0,20,30],
      TextButton.icon(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.description), label: Text("Label")),
      secondDescription: "Is the container completely separate from the plane?",
      secondWidget:  TextButton.icon(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.description), label: Text("Label")),
  );
````

and here I display the card:

````
                missionNumber: mission3.missionNumber,
                missionName: mission3.missionName,
                description: mission3.description,
                points: mission3.points,
                widget: mission3.widget,
                secondDescription: mission3.secondDescription,
                secondWidget: mission3.secondWidget,
             ),```
````

Comment: The debug console will pin point to the exact location, where he received NULL, please check that and see if this helps. If not, please edit your question and add the error message or at least point out which line is causing the issue.

Comment: Add the error to the question.